# Access the row name using variable in r

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, apply, lapply

i have  data table look like

[image]

this is my code

```
while(i<=gh)
{
    fg<-rownames(L2_table)
    na<-fg[i]
    temp<-data.frame()
    temp<-comb[,na]
    gh<-gh+1
}
```

but here variable `na` is not working.it stored as "2"
so i couldn't use as `comb[,na]`.how to over come this?

i want output as  if `row name is 1` take `column 1  of comb` and so on?

Comment: Please learn how to use dput(data) to post your data, makes everybody's life easier.

Comment: Try to state the question more clearly. It is not clear what you need to do. Also, a better layout would help people reading..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`comb[,as.numeric(temp[1])]`

`comb[,as.numeric(temp[3])]`